# Swift access helper function view

Tags: swift, function

I try to access the function "addNavBar()" from, my helper class, but when I run the emulator, no view is shown on HomeViewController.

Swift 4

HomeViewController.swift

```
class HomeController: UIViewController {
let NavBar = NavigationBarHelper()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NavBar.addNavBar()
}
```

}

NavigationBarHelper.swift

```
class NavigationBarHelper: UIView {
    func addNavBar() {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 10, y: 70, width: 250, height: 100)
        let navBarView = UIView(frame: rect)
        navBarView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        self.addSubview(navBarView)
    }
}
```

Comment: You posted the same snippet twice

Comment: sorry. Corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` in NavigationBarHelper is not the same object as the view in the view controller. Pass the VC's view as a parameter. There is no need to make NavigationBarHelper a subclass of UIView (in fact it could also be a struct).

```
class NavigationBarHelper {
    func addNavBar(to view: UIView) {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 10, y: 70, width: 250, height: 100)
        let navBarView = UIView(frame: rect)
        navBarView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        view.addSubview(navBarView)
    }
}
```

please also stick to naming conventions

```
class HomeController: UIViewController {
let navBarHelper = NavigationBarHelper()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navBarHelper.addNavBar(to: self.view)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like charme.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating an object every usage

```
let NavBar = NavigationBarHelper()
```

I think it's more robust to make it `static` like this

```
class NavigationBarHelper: UIView {
 static func addNavBar(view:UIView) {
    let rect = CGRect(x: 10, y: 70, width: 250, height: 100)
    let navBarView = UIView(frame: rect)
    navBarView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    view.addSubview(navBarView)
 }
}
```

and call it directly without object creation

```
NavigationBarHelper.addNavBar(view: self.view)
```

Comment: What makes this more robust?

Comment: creating useless vars is not preferred plus it's the best approcah for utility classes

Comment: But what makes this more robust? Creating an object should not be a problem in a object oriented language. Objects are more easily passable therefore they are behaving nicer in testing situations and allow you to follow the DIP principle. In general I would not say that they are preferred.

Answer (score -1):

A Better Alternative for this would be an `extension` so you don't have to create the special class for this

```
extension UIView {
    func addNavBar() {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 10, y: 70, width: 250, height: 100)
        let navBarView = UIView(frame: rect)
        navBarView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        self.addSubview(navBarView)
    }
}
```

And in you `UIViewController` you can simply write this without creating an object of your helper.

```
self.view.addNavBar()
```

Comment: why would adding this to every view object be a better solution? Does it make sense to add navigation bars to labels or buttons?